# Adding non existing data to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL query returns the following result ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ybb6.png)):

```
x           y           count
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           10
1           2           2
2           4           3
2           5           5
4           1           5
5           1           8
```

what i want is x, y should always contain 1 to 5 values, even if the query doesn't return them, in the above scenario x is missing 3. How to add the missing values here that are between 1 & 5.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
select t1.x, t2.y, s.count from 
(values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) t1(x) cross join
(values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) t2(y)  
left join #temp s on t1.x = s.x and t2.y = s.y
```

Comment: Hi it was close, i need to apply the same for Y column as well, i'm using it to plot those values on a chart i.e. 5*5=25, so i've to get all the combinations and when if a combinations is not having count it should return either null or zero... Thanks for responding

Comment: Added that functionality.

Comment: @GeekExplorer you can't. But You can Upvote for both

Comment: @Giorgi, i've same result set generating from the query, how can use that to do the same....like i'm getting 10 records from query, now i should get 25 records.

Comment: @GeekExplorer, the query from answer should provide 25 rows minimum

Answer (score 3):

First you need to *generate* the desired data. You can use a table of numbers for this. Use `CROSS JOIN` to generate all possible combinations of two tables. Finally, `OUTER JOIN` the generated data with your table.

In the following query I have used union to build a list of numbers instead of fetching them from a table. But the idea remains same:

```
SELECT XList.x, YList.y, #temp.count
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL
    SELECT 2      UNION ALL
    SELECT 3      UNION ALL
    SELECT 4      UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
) AS XList 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 2      UNION ALL
    SELECT 3      UNION ALL
    SELECT 4      UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
) AS YList
LEFT JOIN #temp ON XList.x = #temp.x AND YList.y = #temp.y
```

Result:

```
x           y           count
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           10
2           1           NULL
3           1           NULL
4           1           5
5           1           8
1           2           2
2           2           NULL
3           2           NULL
4           2           NULL
5           2           NULL
1           3           NULL
2           3           NULL
3           3           NULL
4           3           NULL
5           3           NULL
1           4           NULL
2           4           3
3           4           NULL
4           4           NULL
5           4           NULL
1           5           NULL
2           5           5
3           5           NULL
4           5           NULL
5           5           NULL
```

Comment: Hi Salman it was close, but i want to have a Y value as well, with any of 0 to 5 value, plz tell me how to modify ur query to get that. Thanks alot and can u explain your query. I'm new to SQL.

Comment: What is the expected result. I am guessing the result will have 30 rows.

Comment: ha Exactly 25 rows as 5* 5 = 25...but only few combinations will have values remaining zeros or nulls(i.e. count value)

Comment: how to accept both the answers? both are working for me, thanks a lot :)